# How to fix this datediff error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2017

I am looking for the date difference between dates in the 'Dates' column. The query is also converting the Dates column to yyyy-mm-dd format and Filedate column to only display date. the query is being executed in a staging table. I am getting this error and it seems minor but I dont know where and how to correct it: "Parse error at line: 2, column: 19: Incorrect syntax near '('."

```
SELECT
    CONVERT([DATE], date) AS Dates, 
    CAST(filedate AS DATE) AS Filedates, 
    filesize,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, a1.(CONVERT([DATE], date)), a2.(CONVERT([DATE], date))) AS difference 
FROM
    stage.petsmart a1 
INNER JOIN
    stage.petsmart a2 ON a2.id = a1.id + 1
WHERE 
    filesize < 6000
```

Comment: Instead of `a1.(CONVERT([DATE], date))`, write `CONVERT(a1.[DATE], date)`. And so on.

Comment: I tried it. I got this error: "Unsupported data type error. Statement references a data type that is unsupported in Parallel Data Warehouse, or there is an expression that yields an unsupported data type. Modify the statement and re-execute it."

Comment: That's weird, [documentation on date](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) shows that it is supported in parallel data warehouse. Try `CAST(a1.[DATE] AS DATE)`? If it keeps complaining, maybe you can try the `DATETIME` data type instead. (I have no experience with parallel data warehouse). Could also be that the data in the [DATE] columns is not suitable for conversion to the date datatype. You may fiddle with the [convert styles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: See if that works. You also have to ask the question, why is date data not stored with the DATE or DATETIME datatype in the first place.